# Redirect already logged in user Symfony2

Tags: symfony

is there a way to redirect an already logged in user to the main page? For example, those with cookies or "remember me"?

I tried this in my "loginController" but it doesn't work

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();
   // $user = new Usuario();

    // get the login error if there is one
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }
    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
    if( $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') ){
       $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MonsePanelBundle_homepage'));
    }
    return $this->render('UsuariosBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        // last username entered by the user
        'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

I've read all the other similar questions but no luck so far...

this is my security.yml just in case...

```
security:
encoders:
   Monse\UsuariosBundle\Entity\Usuario:
        algorithm: sha512
        encode-as-base64: true
        iterations: 10

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    user_db:
        entity: { class: Monse\UsuariosBundle\Entity\Usuario, property: usuario }

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: /.*
        provider: user_db
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            remember_me: true
            default_target_path: /panel
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
        remember_me:
            key: MiClaveSegura
            lifetime: 1800
            path: /.*
            domain: ~
        security: true
        anonymous: true
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/panel, roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER] }
```

Comment: Wouldn't redirecting someone that is previously logged in mean that the only page they can go to is the one specified?

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand your question.

Comment: My understanding of the question was to forward users that are 'already logged on' into a specific page. But all users after being logged on would then become part of the 'already logged on' group so would only be able to go to that page, due to the forwarding. I'm thinking that that isn't your plan so it's probably just my lack understanding of the problem.

Comment: The page i want the already logged on users to go is the main website page, meaning, already logged on users would skip the "login" page which is what i want.

Comment: So am I right in thinking... Logged in user goes to login_check > splash page > index.. and normal user will just go to index? Could you not just set the splash page as the `default_target_path` in security.yml so logged in users would go to that. Alternatively you could customize the `AuthenticationHandler` using the `onAuthenticationSuccess` method.

Comment: Or do you want them to not see the login page?

Comment: i want them to be redirected to "index" whenever they access to "login"

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. Could you not do a check for a token and user on  the login controller and if found forward to the index page, else continue on and do the regular login stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are times when you need to execute a method on a controller before every action and sometimes on multiple controllers. I.e. if you want to check if user is logged in.

My code is a customization of https://matt.drollette.com/2012/06/calling-a-method-before-every-controller-action-in-symfony2/

If you apply it to a controller, it checks if user is logged in. If so it won't show landing page. but you can redirect the user to any page of your project

---

Create a new Bundle beside UsuariosBundle, name it CoreBundle. In this bundle create two folders EventListener and Model. In Model create:

```
interface InitializableControllerInterface
{
    public function initialize(Request $request, 
                               SecurityContextInterface $security_context, 
                               FilterControllerEvent $event);
}
```

In EventListener create:

```
class BeforeControllerListener
{
    private $security_context;

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $security_context)
    {
        $this->security_context = $security_context;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        if (!is_array($controller)) {
            // not a object but a different kind of callable. Do nothing
            return;
        }

        $controllerObject = $controller[0];

        // skip initializing for exceptions
        if ($controllerObject instanceof ExceptionController) {
            return;
        }

        if ($controllerObject instanceof InitializableControllerInterface) {
            // this method is the one that is part of the interface.
            $controllerObject->initialize($event->getRequest(),
                                          $this->security_context, $event);
        }
    }
}
```

In the classes you do not need to do any customization. Just copy&paste them. Say you have a DefaultController where index action points to the landing page by default. You may want to prevent a logged in user to see landing page, because it has only promotional content:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller 
                        implements InitializableControllerInterface {

    /* Do not show landing page if user is logged in */

    public function initialize(Request $request, 
                               SecurityContextInterface $security_context, 
                               FilterControllerEvent $event) {

        $parent = $this;

        $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');

        if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') ||
            $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {

            if ($parent->container->get('request')->get('_route') != 
                                                   'my_homepage') {
                //nothing
            } else {
                $event->setController(function() use ($parent) {
                return new RedirectResponse(
                           $parent->generateUrl('my_user'));
                        });
            }
        }
    }

   //your code
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

You missed the 'return' in your redirect line

```
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
if($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')){
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MonsePanelBundle_homepage'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement your security Listener like this

```
 public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $this->dispatcher->addListener(KernelEvents::RESPONSE, array($this, 'onKernelResponse'));
    }
 public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER')) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('route1'));
        } 

        elseif ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('route2'));
        } 


        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
```

Look here for more info http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html